# I wanna know how this function works

Tags: go, pointers

```
func NewAccount(owner string) *Account {
    account := Account{owner: owner, balance: 0}
    return &account
}
```

In this code, I wanna know how this function works.
Why did return use '&'? Why did return type use '*'? I wonder how they work.

I googled many times but I didn't find good explains in Korean. So I came here to ask. I got this function's return and return's type are for not copying variable for memory.

Comment: The [Tour of Go](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1) covers these basics, and has been translated into [Korean](https://go-tour-ko.appspot.com/welcome/1) too

Comment: The function returns a pointer to the `Account` struct allocated in the function. `&account` means the address of the `account` object. `*Account` means pointer to an `Account` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*Account` means the function will return a pointer to a variable. This variable must be of type `account`.

`account` (lowercase 'a') is a variable only within the scope of the function.
`:=` is assigning it to the type and value of `Account`.

`Account` is a struct. A struct is a custom data type which holds other data. In this case, an `Account` contains: `owner` and `balance`. `owner` seems to be a reference to its owner and `balance` is a number.

`return &account` returns the address of the variable `account`. A pointer is an address of a variable so this satisfies the return value of this function.